# Opacity: 0 element doesn't get visible when hovered

Tags: html, css

I'm having some problems setting an element with absolute position and width, height 100% to 1.0 opacity.

Long story short, I have this HTML code:

```
<ul class="properties">
    <li style="width: 343px; height: 248px;">
        <img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/parallax/apartment2.png">
        <div class="full">asd</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

And this CSS code:

```
.properties {
    list-style: none;
}

.properties li {
    background-color: #efece9;
    position: relative;
}

.properties li .full {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    /* transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out;
      -webkit-transition: opacity .25s ease-in-out; */
}

.properties li:hover .properties li .full {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

However when I'm hovering over the li, it doesn't set "full" div's opacity to 1. It just stays as it was. When I set its initial opacity to 1 though, it works perfectly fine (covers the whole li with a white background)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selector should be:

```
.properties li:hover .full {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

The reason the selector `.properties li:hover .properties li .full` wasn't working was because the children `li` elements don't have a child with class `.properties`. Only the parent `ul` element has a class of `.properties`.

Once you have narrowed the scope of the selector down to `.properties li:hover`, you are selecting the children from there. In this case, a child with class `.full`.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selector is incorrect. It should be:

```css
.properties li:hover .full {
    opacity: 1;
}
```